# Best way interpolate 4D Data with new Grid

Tags: python, scipy

For example I have data `(x,y,z,v)` and have `(mxnxo)` dimension for each variable and looks like :

[image]

Iam want to make grid dimension using `np.mgrid` for making voxels for visualization  and I interpolating using `scipy.griddata`. But it's so slow because i have huge data (more than 200x300x700) and take 2 days to finish this interpolation.
I try `scipy.LinearNDInterpolator` but still take more than 10 hours to finish it.
Here my script using 'griddata':

```
coordinate = (gx.reshape(m*n*o,),gy.reshape(m*n*o,),gz.reshape(m*n*o,))
data1 = data.reshape(m*n*o,)
a = 15
b = 30
c = 30
xx,yy,zz = np.mgrid[np.min(gx):np.max(gx):a*1j,
                    np.min(gy):np.max(gy):b*1j,np.min(gz):np.max(gz):c*1j]
vv = griddata(coordinate,data1,(xx,yy,zz))
```

Comment: Interpolate to a lower resolution? Please add the code you are using for both the methods you've mentioned

Comment: @Dan yup. For `griddata` and `LinearNDInterpolato` working well, but need huge time.

Comment: Why `a*1j`, are you working with complex numbers?

Comment: @Dan nope, that's the simple way i know to make `(axbxc)` grid with `np.mgrid`

Comment: Why not just `a` instead of `a*1j`? Also rename `a` to `step_x`

Comment: @Dan First, i have small interval between `max(gx)` and `min(gx)`, so most easy to make like that compare make a to step_x